# How to post a Recent Activity on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-activity, scribe

Is it possible to post an activity on facebook? I was thinking of something like this

"Has Posted A Photo `<MyWebSite URL Here>`" Is it possible? if so how? I've tried looking at the docs but I could not find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by integrating [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) into your application. You would need to create custom [Objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/) and [Actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/) as there is no such Common objects, for photo, available as of now in Open Graph.
You can also look into [creating custom stories](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories/) as per your requirements.

**Update** 
Java third party library that you can use :- [Spring Social](http://www.springsource.org/spring-social/)
You can utilize its method [post()](http://static.springsource.org/spring-social-facebook/docs/1.0.x/api/org/springframework/social/facebook/api/impl/FacebookTemplate.html#post%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap%29) to Publish action to `/{user-id}/{namespace}:{action-type-name}` with the required parameters to create the story.

Comment: is there a plugin for that for Java?

Comment: I see, but using Spring Social is not really an option for us. is there a manual way to send a POST request in Servlet?

Comment: @user962206 you can perform a POST to `/{user-id}/{namespace}:{action-type-name}` with the required parameters mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/)

Comment: so the url would be directly like this ? me/{user-id}/{namespace} ? no more http://facebook.com/someurl here?

Comment: @user962206 The Full path to the resource were you should post would be `http://graph.facebook.com/me/{namespace}:{Action-type-name}` with the reference to you Object. But prior to this you would have to create the necessary action and object in Open Graph settings of you App. An example is mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/#publish) for publishing an Action `POST http://graph.facebook.com/me/cookbook:eat?recipe=http://www.example.com/recipes/pizza/&access_token=VALID_ACCESS_TOKEN`.